# The method getHostConfiguration() is undefined for the type HttpClient

Tags: java, proxy, twilio, apache-commons-httpclient

Trying to get Twilio working with a proxy but I get:

> The method getHostConfiguration() is undefined for the type HttpClient

in the following code:

```
TwilioRestClient client = new TwilioRestClient(ACCOUNTSID, AUTHTOKEN);
client.getHttpClient().getHostConfiguration().setProxy("1.1.1.1", "8080");
```

The imports I have are:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.Credentials;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HostConfiguration;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethod;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpStatus;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.UsernamePasswordCredentials;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.auth.AuthScope;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.GetMethod;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import com.twilio.sdk.TwilioRestClient;
import com.twilio.sdk.TwilioRestException;
import com.twilio.sdk.TwilioRestResponse;
import com.twilio.sdk.resource.factory.SmsFactory;
import com.twilio.sdk.resource.instance.Account;
import com.twilio.sdk.resource.instance.Sms;
```

Comment: Can you post what object class do you obtain with `client.getHttpClient()`? Is it really `org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient`? Note that `twilioClient.getHttpClient()` gives `org.apache.http.client.HttpClient` ([see this](http://twilio.github.io/twilio-java/com/twilio/sdk/TwilioClient.html#getHttpClient--)) but the API `HttpClient` does not imply you have the method `getHostConfiguration()` available. I don't really know about Twilio, but I'd suggest you take a look a object you really get from `TwilioRestClient`.